# How to get post ID in post_updated action hook?

Tags: hooks, actions

I want to execute a function, myfunction() [hypothetically named], whenever a page is updated in the admin. The function doesn't do anything to the content that is saved—it just runs an unrelated task elsewhere.

I read that the `post_updated` hook is good to use for this, but I cannot seem to get this code to run:

```
add_action('post_updated', 'myfunction');

function myfunction() {
    // check if this is a page
    $id = get_the_id();
    if ( is_page($id) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious; do I have to pass in/return parameters ($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before, 
from what I gather in the [Wordpress Hooks Database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post_updated?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/post.php)) for it to work? If I just want the ID, do I still have to pass in/return the other two?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the ID of the post through the `$_POST` variable.

**EDIT:** Maybe you should try doing this on the `save_post` action, like so, but `save_post` sometimes runs on other instances (ie. Autosave Drafts), so you'll want to do some more verifying. `save_post` will also return the ID as one of the function arguments so you already have that handy.

```
add_action('save_post', 'myfunction');

function myfunction( $id ) {

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // check if this is a page
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        // Return nothing if the user can't edit this page
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $id ) )
            return;

        // do stuff here, we have verified this is a page and you can edit it

    }

}
```

Just tested this on localhost, works good for me.

Used a bit of code [from here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and you should read up on the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action if you decide to try this out!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Things I have double-checked: The function works if I change the conditional to 1 == 1. The post  I'm testing with is a page.

Comment: @supertrue What exactly are you trying to do? Just return the ID of the page that was updated? See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

get_the_ID() should work, I use it for a very similar purpose.

The hooks I use it on are

```
add_action('future_to_publish','123_total_calculator');
add_action('new_to_publish','123_total_calculator');
add_action('draft_to_publish','123_total_calculator');
add_action('publish_post','123_total_calculator');
```

Comment: Not trying to hijack this but I tried running get_the_ID() on add_action('edit_post', myFunction) and it failed. Any luck with you?

Comment: @AlxVallejo get_the_id() worked for me using the `wp_insert_post_data` action hook/filter with priority `99` set on a post, both updating existing and a new one. Only 5 years later, but good for other to reference in the future. ;)